# How to pass json to fix cross origin problem in google chrome

Tags: html, json, ajax, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to run a html file which is on my local file path.In my html page it retrieves some json data. While running it on google chrome it shows No records and shows error as "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https". I want to run it on multiple system which is not connected via LAN. So I can't run the file via web server. Is there any other possible? Please let me know. Thanks in Advance.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#mytable",
ready: function() {

var json = (function () {
var json = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'sii.json',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
    }
});
return json;
})(); 

this.tableData = json;
}
data: {
columns: ['Source','Place'],
tableData: [],
options: {
perPageValues: [80,100],
headings: {

  },
templates: {

 }
 }
 }
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I tried all the possibilities to disable the web security, allow 
 file access. But its not working well. Am asking is there any possible to pass allow access argument through code? Because i have to run this code multiple system. Its not good to change chrome settings in every systems manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local hope this helps